# Taking average of two rows and adding third row of same column in sql

Tags: sql, relational-database

I'm doing a simple student marks report application and trying to create a View Object through sql statement from two entity object in the database.
StudentDetails -> rollno, name.
marks -> rollno, internal, sub1, sub2, sub3

there are two exams for the students i.e. internal=1 and internal=2 and internal=3 is for assignment submission marks.

snapshot of marks table is below. DRAWING table as i'm not able to attach snapshot here.

select * from marks shows like this:

```
---------------------------------
ROLLNO | INTERNAL | SUB1 | SUB2 |
1      | 1        | 12   | 15   |
1      | 2        | 15   | 17   |
1      | 3        | 2    | 5    |
2      | 1        | 10   | 14   |
--------------------------------
```

For calculating aggregate marks we have to avg marks from internal=1 and internal=2 and add marks of internal=3 to it for every rollno(student). Can someone please help me in framing this query.

Comment: Please saw your work?

Comment: I suggest adding desired output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have no clue what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question exactly what is being averaged to give the result, but here is an attempt which you can build on.

I will break up your question into parts.

*For calculating aggregate marks we have to avg marks* - so we will be using the `AVG( )` function.

*from internal=1 and internal=2* - so that will go in the `WHERE` clause as `WHERE internal=1 or internal=2`.

*and add marks of internal=3 to it*  tricky - will need to treat the rows with internal=3 as a separate table and use `JOIN` to link them.

*for every rollno(student)* so, we are combining rows by student, which requires a `GROUP BY`.

Here is the final statement:

```
select m1.rollno, avg(m1.sub1+m1.sub2)+m2.sub1+m2.sub2 as result
from marks as m1
inner join marks as m2
on m1.rollno = m2.rollno
where m1.internal in (1,2) 
and m2.internal = 3
group by rollno
```

Here is a working example for you to experiment on: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ed4e0/1

The way it is averaging and adding may be incorrect, but it was difficult to discern from your question what you really needed. It should be easy to change this part.

Note that since rows with internal=3 represent a different type of data they should be in a different table unless you have the experience to be certain what you are doing is workable.